# Why can't I insert NULL value into column after MySQL upgrade?

Tags: php, mysql

After upgrade my mysql I have problem with database. In logs I can see:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'kod_tecdoc' cannot be null in.

when I tried insert or update row in table.
I'm suprised becouse before upgrading works good. My table fields allows to empty values. I know that solution may be

> if ($kod_tecdoc == null) $kod_tecdoc = '';

but it doesn't resolve problem. Maybe some settings should be changed in mysql ?
my mysql version:

```
+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 5.7.12-0ubuntu1 |
+-----------------+
```

Table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `Realizacje` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `tekst_allegro` text NOT NULL,
      `typy_felg` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `nazwa` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      `nazwa_allegro` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `producent` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `cena_netto_gielda` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_brutto_gielda` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_netto_hurt` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_brutto_hurt` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_netto_warsztat` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `cena_brutto_warsztat` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `vat` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `kod_produkt` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `on_pojazdy` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `on_zamienniki` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `on_kategoria` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `kod` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `kod_dostawcy` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `kod_tecdoc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `widoczny` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `dostepny` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `dostepnosc` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `promocja` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `promocja_glowna` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `nowosc` varchar(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `nowosc_glowna` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `glowna` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
      `bestseller` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0',
      `bestseller_glowna` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `polecamy` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `polecamy_glowna` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `skrot` text NOT NULL,
      `tekst` text,
      `odwiedziny` bigint(20) DEFAULT '0',
      `lang` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'pl',
      `status` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
      `link` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
      `route_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
      `miary` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `rabat` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
      `narzut` varchar(1) DEFAULT '0',
      `aukcje` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `stan` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
      `aktualizowany` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
      `dostawanatelefon` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
      `dodano` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `aktualizacja` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `kosztyAllegro` text NOT NULL,
      `allegroCennik` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `trybCena` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `allegro_ok` varchar(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      `ogranicz_ilosc_znakow` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '50'
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: SO show us the schema for that table

Comment: empty values is not null. Change the field to be nullable.

Comment: I'm working on local database  which is copy of base on server. On server works good. I'm curious what happend after upgrading. I have 130 tables in my project. Changing all firlds will be very long.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your local MySQL server is running in "strict" mode, which throws an error in case like yours, and several others that are otherwise handled "gracefully" without strict mode. As of MySQL 5.7.5, the default SQL mode includes `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES`, which is exactly the cause of your headache.

To change your local server's mode, edit your `my.cnf` (or `my.ini` if you're running Windows) and then set the mode to:

`sql-mode=""`

Or, upon connecting to MySQL in your web app, execute this query first right after the connection is estabilished:

`SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';`

I'd advise against this because it lets you execute a bit careless statements. In the long run, you're better off with [adjusting your schema instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870530/mysql-cannot-insert-null-value-in-column#36870917).

Comment: +1 excellent answer to why, I suggested an edit to reference [@Alvaro's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870530/mysql-cannot-insert-null-value-in-column#36870917)

Comment: It really helps! Thanks. I put     sql_mode = '' to mysql.cnf and now works. Previously I tried resolve problem with sql_mode=only_full_group_by and I found solution: set global sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION'; but in this case doesn't works.

Comment: i'm glad i helped :) I've accepted your edit @JeffPuckettII, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> My table fields allows to empty values.

That's not true:

```
`kod_tecdoc` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
                         ^^^^^^^^
```

If the column is really optional, alter the table and make it `NULL`able.

Comment: The point is that I didn't change table structure and it works fine before upgrade mysql to 5.7.12 and on the server copy of this database works fine too. I'm curious what happend, where is the difference? The problem appeares in many fields and in many tables.

Comment: your old engine was imputing the value `''`, see [@drndavi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36870530/mysql-cannot-insert-null-value-in-column#36871020)

Comment: You've probably changed the default SQL_MODE variable.